filtering out date in string based on datediff?
I have a filter calc where I want to bring in columns from 'Master Line List' worksheet. First iteration of the calc worked, but I appended logic to search in rows from column C. Find the first date value and if that <= 7 days from today, then bring in the matching data from the rest of the column. If the first date found is older than that then don't bring data in.
=IFNA(UNIQUE(FILTER({'Master Line List'!C:C,'Master Line List'!F:F,'Master Line `List'!E:E,'Master Line List'!G:G},`

 (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())-7),"mm/dd/yyyy"), 

'Master Line List'!C:C))), 'Master Line List'!E:E=C1, 'Master Line List'!G:G=D1)),"")

So based on sheet 'Metrics', I select c1 dropdown = Dan and d1 dropdown = Outreach. If you go into 'Master Line List' you can see column G has 4 rows that have Dans name, but only 2 of those rows have a date in column F that has a date that is a week or less from today.
What do I need to change to get the correct rows brought in?
link to workbook


You may try:
=filter(choosecols('Master Line List'!C:G,1,4,3,5),
         'Master Line List'!G:G=C1,'Master Line List'!E:E=D1,
          isbetween(ifna(--regexextract('Master Line List'!F:F,"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}")),today()-7,today()))


